# combining multiple rows with arbitrary number of columns

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to format a query but, I don't think I know all the required methods to do what I want currently I have these results

```
Source
------
item    |PackQty|TotalUsage |JobDescription|job_usage   
STE0295 |5      |20         |41721-2       |1
STE0295 |5      |20         |41925-1       |1
STE0295 |5      |20         |41949-1       |1
STE0295 |5      |20         |41997-1       |1
```

and I want to combine all item keys into a single row like this

```
STE0295 |5      |20         |41721-2       |1   |41925-1    |1  |41949-1    |1  |41997-1    |1
```

These results are not the entire set; there are thousand of unique 'item' records and they appear in arbitrary number of rows based on the different job Description. I have used pivots before and also the stuff for xml method but, I feel like I am missing some concepts to achieve this format. Here is the query so far

```
    select  tv.Item,
       --tv.ItemDescription,
       tv.PackQty,
       TotalUsage = (
                        SELECT sum(tvss.Qty * -1)
                        FROM transactions_VIEW as tvss
                        WHERE tvss.Item = tv.Item
                          AND TranDateTime between '2019-04-01 00:00:00.000' and '2019-04-30 11:59:59.000'
                          AND tvss.Supplier IN ('###', '###', '###')
                          AND tvss.TranType IN ('I','B')
                    ),
       tv.JobDescription,
    count(*) as job_usage
from transactions_VIEW as tv
         join Job as j on tv.JobNumber = j.MyNo
WHERE j.Active = 1
  AND TranDateTime between '2019-04-01 00:00:00.000' and '2019-04-30 11:59:59.000'
  AND tv.Supplier IN ('###', '###','###')
  AND tv.TranType IN ('I', 'B')
group by tv.Item, tv.JobDescription, tv.ItemDescription, Qty, PackQty
```

I have looked around but, I don't know the name of the technique to use so I am floundering. Any pointers in the right directions would be awesome.

Comment: Assuming that you want actual columns with the differing data, you can't do this inside of SQL Server... with the minor exception that, if you want to write a query to determine the maximum number of records there are per item, then you theoretically could write dynamic SQL code that would return what you are looking for. If they don't actually have to be separate columns in the output, then there are possible techniques for this.  Nonetheless, SQL Server is not the best tool for this.

Comment: The most straightforward method inside SQL Server will involve at least one cursor, or XML output, or JSON output. The cursor method will likely be too slow and resource intensive. And, unfortunately, I don't really have enough XML / JSON output experience to perform this task. This also brings up a question - why only one row?

Comment: its a report generation. I am trying to make it more useful by eliminating duplicate item records. Previously I did a pivot over the job description and job_usage. that works great but only when there are a small number of job descriptions. now i am trying to get it to look like a sheet that has the arbitrary key1,value1,key2,value2 fields .

Comment: This can probably be much simpler. Is there a smaller table where `transactions_VIEW` is getting `Item` and `PackQty`?

Comment: there is yes. however it doesn't simplify much. I would actually have to track about 10-15 joins in order to replace the view i am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well it looks like I will use stuff xml again and parse out in application. however if any one knows any clever rearrangement of this query using cte's and cross or outer applys I would love to hear it.

```
        select distinct tv.Item,
       --tv.ItemDescription,
       tv.PackQty,
       TotalUsage = (
                        SELECT sum(tvss.Qty * -1)
                        FROM transactions_VIEW as tvss
                        WHERE tvss.Item = tv.Item
                          AND TranDateTime between '2019-04-01 00:00:00.000' and '2019-04-30 11:59:59.000'
                          AND tvss.Supplier IN ('###', '###', '###')
                          AND tvss.TranType IN ('I','B')
                    ),
       [jobDesc:use] = STUFF((SELECT ';' + CAST(tvs.JobDescription as nvarchar(max)) +':'+CAST(count(*) as nvarchar(max))
                          from transactions_VIEW as tvs
                                   join Job as js on tvs.JobNumber = js.MyNo
                          WHERE js.Active = 1
                            AND TranDateTime between '2019-04-01 00:00:00.000' and '2019-04-30 11:59:59.000'
                            AND tvs.Supplier IN ('###', '###','###')
                            AND tvs.TranType IN ('I', 'B')
                            AND tvs.Item = tv.Item
                          Group By tvs.JobDescription FOR XML Path ('')), 1, 1, '')
from transactions_VIEW as tv
         join Job as j on tv.JobNumber = j.MyNo
WHERE j.Active = 1
  AND TranDateTime between '2019-04-01 00:00:00.000' and '2019-04-30 11:59:59.000'
  AND tv.Supplier IN ('###', '###','###')
  AND tv.TranType IN ('I', 'B')
group by tv.Item, tv.JobDescription, tv.ItemDescription, Qty, PackQty
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay parsing on the app side and you have SQL Server 2016 or newer, you can use JSON:

```
SELECT tv.Item
     , tv.PackQty
     , TotalUsage = (SELECT SUM(tvss.Qty * -1)
                     FROM transactions_VIEW AS tvss
                     WHERE tvss.Item = tv.Item
                           AND TranDateTime BETWEEN '2019-04-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2019-04-30 11:59:59.000'
                           AND tvss.Supplier IN ( '###', '###', '###' )
                           AND tvss.TranType IN ( 'I', 'B' ) )
     , [jobDesc:use] = (SELECT jobDesc = CAST(tvs.JobDescription AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
                             , [use] = CAST(COUNT(*) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
                        FROM transactions_VIEW AS tvs
                             JOIN Job AS js
                               ON tvs.JobNumber = js.MyNo
                        WHERE js.Active = 1
                              AND TranDateTime BETWEEN '2019-04-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2019-04-30 11:59:59.000'
                              AND tvs.Supplier IN ( '###', '###', '###' )
                              AND tvs.TranType IN ( 'I', 'B' )
                              AND tvs.Item = tv.Item
                        GROUP BY tvs.JobDescription 
                        FOR JSON PATH)
FROM transactions_VIEW AS tv
     JOIN Job AS j
       ON tv.JobNumber = j.MyNo
WHERE j.Active = 1
      AND TranDateTime BETWEEN '2019-04-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2019-04-30 11:59:59.000'
      AND tv.Supplier IN ( '###', '###', '###' )
      AND tv.TranType IN ( 'I', 'B' )
GROUP BY tv.Item
       , tv.JobDescription
       , tv.ItemDescription
       , Qty
       , PackQty;
```

Comment: My company is one or 2 incremental upgrades away from 2016 otherwise i would be doing this 110%